# windows service equivalent using .net core hosted in AWS C#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, azure, .net-core, windows-services

I have several windows services that I have written that act as middle-ware to 2 separate vendors.  The service sends requests to the first vendor, processes the response, and sends formatted data to the second vendor.  These processes run every X seconds in the background on the service.  The service uses TCP and json for transport and data types.

These services generally do nothing outside the above description except for logging.

I have been writing with windows/.net for eons and am attempting to venture into either AWS or Azure to run these particular assets.  I have only scratched the surface on Lambda and Functions and already I feel overwhelmed.

Any direction to get started would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps Amazon Step Functions could fit the bill: https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using Azure Functions + Time Trigger. Here's a sample:

```
[FunctionName("TimerTriggerCSharp")]
public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
{
    if (myTimer.IsPastDue)
    {
        log.LogInformation("Timer is running late!");
    }
    log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
}
```

Notice that it has a CRON expression to specify the frequency of the trigger.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer

PS: As far as I know, there's no time trigger on AWS Lambda.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for something integrated, you can look at Hangfire. You can run it as a separate Dot Net Core App, then you would cloud-agnostic. You can still run using a serverless option from either Azure or AWS. It is basically is a task runner that you can schedule recurring code to run, all from c#. The company I work for uses it to send and process e-mail messages as well as pulling and importing data from vendors.

I set it up in an empty Dot Net Core project, that way I can give it its own resources and not slow end-users interactions. It can be attached to an existing application, as well.

You can find more info here: https://www.hangfire.io/

Hope this helps.